# Count the sum of subsets of size k when the sum is (Greater than or equal to R) or (Lesser than or equal to L)

Tags: count, dynamic-programming, subset-sum, bottom-up

```
def knapSack(A,L,R,K,N,Sum):
    if(K==0):
        if((L>=Sum)or(R<=Sum)):
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    if((N==0)and(K!=0)):
        return 0
    else:
        return knapSack(A,L,R,K,N-1,Sum)+knapSack(A,L,R,K-1,N-1,Sum:=Sum+A[N-1])
A = [2,4,10,25]
K = 2
L = 3
R = 13
Sum=0
n = len(A)
print(knapSack(A,L,R,K,n,Sum))
```

The Output Of this Code is: 4
Explanation:
25+10 =35
25+4 = 29
25+2 = 27
10+4 = 14
These Sums satisfies the given condition if((L>=Sum)or(R<=Sum)) where L=3 R=13
K is the size of the subset. Here, K = 2
When K = 3

```
A = [2,4,10,25]
K = 3
L = 3
R = 13
Sum = 0
n = len(A)
print(knapSack(A,L,R,K,n,Sum))
```

The Output Of this Code when K = 3 is: 4
Explanation:
4+10+25 = 39
2+4+25 = 31
2+10+25 = 37
2+4+10 = 16
These Sums satisfies the given condition if((L>=Sum)or(R<=Sum)) where L=3 R=13

Is There a way to solve this problem in Dynamic Programming or any other better way?

Comment: You can simplify the problem by only considering the upper (or lower) bound, then get the final answer by subtraction.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem can you give me the algorithm?

Comment: What are your input? is Sum part of the input? Also, is L always greater than or equal to R?

Comment: @Wilson my inputs will be an Array = [2,4,10,25] , L = 3(Sum can be lesser than equal to L), R = 13(Sum can be Greater than equal to R), N = len(Array). No, L always lesser than or equal to R.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic programming algorithm you can use. The algorithm will be used to generate all subsets of size `K`. This algorithm uses one element of `A` one after another to build subsets.

**STEPS**

1. Initialize a `list` with the `empty set`. Also initialize a `global_counter` which will be used to keep count of subsets of size `K` that satisfies the given condition.
2. Iterate the elements of `A`. For each `A[i]`, do the following;

   **i.** Create **new** subsets by appending `A[i]` to all the current elements in the `list` (Notice that `list` is currently containing the subsets created using `A[0] to A[i-1]`).

   **ii.** For each of the new subsets created in `2.i` using `A[i]`, let `sum` be the sum of the elements in the subset, and `count` be the number of elements in the subset. If `count == K AND (sum <= L OR sum >= R)` then increment the `global_counter`. If `count < K`, insert the newly created subset into the `list`.
3. Return the `global_counter`.

**NB**: Instead of storing every intermediate subset as a list of elements, we will use `(sum, count)` pairs to represent subsets. Where `sum` represent the sum of elements in the subset, while `count` represent the number of elements in the subset. This way we can reduce the memory required to store all the created subsets and the time required to compute the `sum` and `count` each time a subset is created, since `sum` and `count` of the a newly created subset can be updated in constant time from the its previous subset.

**Time Complexity**: O(2^N) - Notice that at worst case, `K = N`

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubsetK {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {2,4,10,25};
        int L = 3;
        int R = 13;

        int K = 3;
        System.out.println("K: "+K+", Result: "+countSubSets(A,K,L,R));
    }

    private static int countSubSets(int[] A, int K, int L, int R){
        //create array to hold subsets of size 0,1,...,(K-1)

        //since we are only interested in the sum of a subset, a subset will be
        //represented as (sum, count) pairs. Where sum is the sum of elements in the
        //subset, and count is the number of elements in the subset.
        
        List<int[]> dp = new ArrayList<>(); // list of [sum,count] pairs

        //initialize the array with the empty set
        dp.add(new int[]{0,0});

        int global_count = 0;
        for (int ele : A) {
            int size = dp.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                
                int sum = dp.get(j)[0] + ele;
                int count = dp.get(j)[1] + 1;

                //check if condition is satisfied
                if (count == K && (sum <= L || sum >= R))
                    global_count++;

                //we only store subsets of size 0,..,(K-1)
                //since they will be used to build bigger subsets
                if (count < K)
                    dp.add(new int[]{sum, count});
            }
        }
        return global_count;
    }
}
```